# Error when compiling in R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have a chuck of code I'm trying to compile in R Markdown.

```
library(jsonlite)
library(rvest)
library(RJSONIO)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

#Create a function that will download movie info
rottenrate <- function(movie){
  require(RJSONIO)
  link <- paste("http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=", movie, "&y=&plot=short&r=json&tomatoes=true", sep = "")
  jsonData <- fromJSON(link)
  return(jsonData)
}
vrottenrate <- Vectorize(rottenrate, "movie", SIMPLIFY = F)
```

When I run this however I'm met with a

```
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
Calls: &lt;Anonymous&gt; ... &lt;Anonymous&gt; -&gt; fromJSON -&gt; fromJSON -&gt; I -&gt; structure -&gt; unique
```

Comment: Generally you just say `Vectorize(fun)`. You have not shown how you actually called that function.

Comment: I just tried this in an Rmd, it ran fine. I suspect that when you call vrottenrate there's an issue.

Comment: whoa buddy, why don't you go accept some of those answers that people have been so kind to help you out with

Comment: God, I didn't even know. Thank you.

Comment: @user1357015 Would you mind just posting a word version if it ran fine?

Comment: @BondedDust There's more code. But this is where I have the error.

Comment: There is no connection between the code you have posted and the actual error message  .... namely no actual call of the function created by `Vectorize`.

Comment: Full code here: [link] https://docs.google.com/document/d/1OPu5AGgmQocYAkbqintZhCajoDyt2-gt7yXeJVwbnDU/edit?usp=sharing